# Screen tearing and audio jitter when play videos on google chrome

Tags: sound, google-chrome, video, flash

Using 16.04  and only seems to happen in chrome.the other question seems to have fixed the flickering problem but i still have like small screen delay when i switch tabs and i still seem to have the sound jitter randomly